# How to add data one level down to IEnumerable type?

Tags: c#, .net, confluent-platform

I am working on .Net project. I have my Product model below.

```
class Product
{
public IEnumerable<OptionData> Options { get; set; }
}
```

Then I have OptionData model below.

```
public class OptionData
  {
    public Colour PrimaryColour { get; set; }

    public Colour SecondaryColour { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<SizeData> Sizes { get; set; }
  }
```

Then I have SizeData model below.

```
public class SizeData
  {
    public string KeycodeNumber { get; set; }

    public Size Size { get; set; }
  }
```

Then I have my size model below.

```
public class Size
  {
    public string Name { get; set; }
  }
```

Then I am sending data using these models to some messaging system. In my case it is confluent kafka.

```
Options = new Option[]
            {
              new Option
              {
                PrimaryColour = new CodeNamePair
                {
                  Name = "White",
                },
                SecondaryColour = new CodeNamePair
                {
                  Name = "red",
                },
                Sizes = new SizeElement[]
                {
                  new SizeElement
                  {
                    Size = new KafkaProductEvent.Size
                    {
                      Name = "10"
                    },
                    KeycodeNumber = 232
                  }
                }
              }
            }
```

Then through consumer I am extracting data. I am able to get PrimaryColour or SecondaryColour as below.

```
IEnumerable<object> options = (IEnumerable<object>)((GenericRecord)response.Message.Value["Product"])["Options"];
      foreach (var data in options)
      {
        OptionData optionData = new OptionData()
        {
          PrimaryColour = new Colour()
          {
            Name = (string)((GenericRecord)((GenericRecord)data)["PrimaryColour"])["Name"],
          },
          SecondaryColour = new Colour()
          {
            Name = (string)((GenericRecord)((GenericRecord)data)["SecondaryColour"])["Name"]
          }
        };
      }
```

Then I want to get Sizes data as well. I tried something like this.

```
Sizes = new SizeData[]
          {
            new SizeData()
            {
              Size = new ProductEvents.Size()
              {
                Name = "";
              }
            }
          }
```

I am not sure how to get size name from above. Can someone help me to find it out. Any help would appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Check the solution I have pasted, which shall help in solving de-serializing the data in to the object hierarchy you are expecting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Main challenge that I see in the code posted by you is the kind of APIs exposed by the client adapter you are using for deserializing the complex data model with multiple aggregated objects, challenge with what you are doing is, typecasting every record in every hierarchy to `GenericRecord`, then typecast to actual .Net type object, which means as the aggregated hierarchy grows, it will make it extremely complex to deserialize the actual object, especially with aggregated collections:

Also a point related to deserializing `Options` :

```
class Product
{
  public IEnumerable<OptionData> Options { get; set; }
}
```

Your code is:

```
IEnumerable<object> options = (IEnumerable<object>)((GenericRecord)response.Message.Value["Product"])["Options"];
```

What I am wondering is why you cannot type cast to `IEnumerable<OptionData>`, to make it little simple and let's assume if that's not possible, then while enumerating through the `IEnumerable<object> options` why it can't still be type casted to the `OptionData` object, challenge with the adapter or approach you are using is that it needs complete object and hierarchy / property name awareness to de-serialize, when ideally once you fill the top level object like `Product` in this case, rest all shall recursively fill in, a good example is `Newtonsoft Json`, it will automatically fill object of any complexity, will make anything unavailable as null / default and require the minimal deserialization code.

Actually what you can do is, develop your own adapter that reads property details via reflection and fill data that is available in the input or discard it. For now assuming, this is all that you have as APIs, then following shall be the approach:

```
IEnumerable<object> options = (IEnumerable<object>)((GenericRecord)response.Message.Value["Product"])["Options"];
    foreach (var data in options)
    {
        OptionData optionData = new OptionData()
        {
            PrimaryColour = new Colour()
            {
                Name = (string)((GenericRecord)((GenericRecord)data)["PrimaryColour"])["Name"],
            },
            SecondaryColour = new Colour()
            {
                Name = (string)((GenericRecord)((GenericRecord)data)["SecondaryColour"])["Name"]
            },
            Sizes = new List<SizeData>() // Initialize Collection Here  
        };

        IEnumerable<object> SizesEnumerable = (IEnumerable<object>)(((GenericRecord)data)["Sizes"]);

        foreach (var size in SizesEnumerable)
        {
            var sizeValue = new SizeData
            {
                KeycodeNumber = (string)((GenericRecord)size)["KeycodeNumber"],
                Size = new Size
                {
                    Name = (string)((GenericRecord)((GenericRecord)size)["Size"])["Name"]
                }
            };

            ((List<SizeData>)optionData.Sizes).Add(sizeValue); // Add Data here
        }
    }
```

> What's the difference ?

1. You are trying to use the object initializer to fill in the `IEnumerable<SizeData> Sizes` to fill in the collection, but that doesn't provide option to do further processing as required in your case
2. Also note I have made `IEnumerable<SizeData> Sizes` as `List<SizeData>`, since we cannot use object initializer, so we cannot use array, since we don't know the size in advance
3. Going further used the same logic as yours to fill the data

Comment: Thanks a lot Mrinal for you your time. GenericRecord I am using it for Avro. Actually I am working on confluent kafka. I cannot directly de-serialize using Newtonsoft Json. Problem is I have to extract each property and assign it to my c# model.

Comment: Welcome Niranjan, I am not suggesting to use Newtonsoft but was providing a client example and how it shall deserialize (just example). Mostly current answer shall provide you a way of how to go about filling a complex hierarchy with APIs available with Avro, little bit more work, but you need more flexible APIs to cut that short